# How to override unique constraint defined in super class

Tags: jpa

Below is the super class which looks something like this.

```
public abstract class BaseType {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "code", length = 8, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code;

    .........

}
```

And i have inherited this class and created an JPA Entity looks like this.

```
public class ChildEntity extends BaseType {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "group_id", nullable = false)
    private Long groupId;

    ......
}
```

I need to create a combination of "code" and "group_id" as a unique.

I have tried adding uniqueConstraints but did not work. And only "code" is always considered as unique but not both.

```
@Table(name = "table_name", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "code", "group_id"}))
```

How can i override unique="true" defined in BaseType in the subclass.

Please help.

Comment: You try to add code and group_id as the key of the entity? . Another question is: Which one is the PK?.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@AttributeOverride` annotation :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
@AttributeOverride(name = "code", column = @Column(name = "code", unique = false))
public class ChildEntity extends BaseType {

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "group_id", nullable = false)
private Long groupId;
}
```